# Is there a good user auth service?

Tags: web-apps, api, saas, authentication, user-management

Is there a service that lets me outsource user management for my web apps?

Specifically, I am looking for service which can provide a user login page, forgot password feature, role and access management. I would redirect user to those pages for authentication, and make use of returned ticket/token to check authentication server side using API.

I would not need to maintain database of users and credentials etc.

If such service does not exist, what could be the reason?

Comment: Web sites usually use oAuth in such a scenario. All those "Login with Google/Facebook/Twitter/Github" and so on buttons basically use oAuth. But you still need to store some data, otherwise you could not reidentify a user and the data she/he has created on your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement "Social login" for your application. This allows people to log in using Google, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Yahoo, Microsoft, and any other service you choose to support. The only downside is that not all users will have accounts at your chosen providers and some users won't want to link their social accounts to your service.

Alternatively, you can use a service like [Okta](https://www.okta.com), [OneLogin](https://www.onelogin.com), and many other similar services that provide "Identity" services.

Comment: Hi Moshe. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction (Identity Management Services).